# Zend Unit Test with database

Tags: php, database, zend-framework, testing

I want to make some unit tests in my project (i am new to testing), but tutorials online seem to show examples testing only simpliest stuff.

What I want to test is case when after sending POST to addAction in my SurveyController will result in adding corresponding rows to my survey and question tables (one-to-many).

What are the best practices to test database related stuff? Do I create separate db for my test environment and run tests on it? That is the only and right option?

Comment: Best practise is to mock the database, so you can control the responses to test different results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your circumstances.

Here is my take on this:

The idea is to test but also be [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't repeat yourself). Your tests must cover all or as many different cases as possible to ensure that your component is thoroughly tested and ready to be released.

If you use an already developed framework to access your database like [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com), [PhalconPHP](http://www.phalconphp.com) etc. then you can assume that the framework has been tested and not test the actual CRUD operations. You can concentrate on what your own code does.

Some people might want to test even that but in my view it is an overkill and waste of resources. One can actually include the tests of the particular framework with their own if they want to just have more tests :)

If however you were responsible for the database layer classes and its interaction with your application, yeah tests are a must. You might not run them all the time you need to prove a database operation works or not through some piece of code, but you need to have them.

Finally you can use Mock tests as [Mark Baker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) suggested in your code and assume that the database will respond as you expect it to (since it has already been tested). You can then see how your application will react with different responses or results.

Mocking database operations will actually make your tests run faster (along with the other benefits that come with this strategy) since there won't be any database interactions in the tests themselves. This can become really handy in a project with hundreds if not thousands of tests and continuous integration.

HTH